# Scala error with gbt classifier FileNotFoundException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I have a problem when I fit my model, the `df_train` `DataFrame` already have the features vectors and the label vector, but I get this error, and I don't have any idea of what is going on. I tried everything but still I don't know what happens. Maybe it is a problem of memory with Spark or something else.

I try something else, I run the same script in a cluster of Hadoop and works fine, but when I run it in my local machine appears that error

```scala
val gbt = new GBTClassifier().setFeaturesCol("features").setLabelCol("label").setMaxIter(50)
val model = gbt.fit(df_train)
```

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-634044d0-c0c8-43c2-b383-aa4c4a1f4f32\36\temp_shuffle_54d1a4b0-8738-4f54-becf-39d8c0d7a129 (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter$$anonfun$revertPartialWritesAndClose$2.apply$mcV$sp(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1386)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.revertPartialWritesAndClose(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.stop(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/03/21 14:27:52 ERROR BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter: Error while deleting file C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-634044d0-c0c8-43c2-b383-aa4c4a1f4f32\36\temp_shuffle_54d1a4b0-8738-4f54-becf-39d8c0d7a129
18/03/21 14:27:52 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 710.0 (TID 706)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-634044d0-c0c8-43c2-b383-aa4c4a1f4f32\36\temp_shuffle_54d1a4b0-8738-4f54-becf-39d8c0d7a129 (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/03/21 14:27:52 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 710.0 (TID 706, localhost, executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-634044d0-c0c8-43c2-b383-aa4c4a1f4f32\36\temp_shuffle_54d1a4b0-8738-4f54-becf-39d8c0d7a129 (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18/03/21 14:27:52 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 710.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
18/03/21 14:27:52 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 710.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
18/03/21 14:27:52 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 710
18/03/21 14:27:52 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 710 (flatMap at RandomForest.scala:921) failed in 0,044 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 710.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 710.0 (TID 706, localhost, executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-634044d0-c0c8-43c2-b383-aa4c4a1f4f32\36\temp_shuffle_54d1a4b0-8738-4f54-becf-39d8c0d7a129 (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:151)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
18/03/21 14:27:52 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 706 failed: collectAsMap at RandomForest.scala:928, took 0,045648 s
```

Comment: Maybe you could describe more precisely *what exactly* you've tried so far, and what reasons you can exclude. For example, are you sure that you are not completely running out of memory or sth. like that?

Comment: I am working with a dataset of 1 mb, for this reason I think that is not an issue of memory, and so far i did'nt try anything else

Comment: Maybe it's due to temp dir permission issues. Check `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp`, set it to 777 or set spark temp dir manually in your code